# Comentarios al final de la linea en SQLPlus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Me he dado cuenta de que si introduzco un comentario tras el símbolo de final de sentencia (;) la instrucción no la ejecuta y tampoco da error, es como si todo a la linea fuera un comentario.

Ejemplo:

```
Insert into MI_TABLA
   (CAMPO1, CAMPO2, CAMPO3, CAMPO4, CAMPO5)
 Values
   ( 311, 'PRUEBA1', 'PRUEBA1', 'PRUEBA1', 1);

INSERT INTO MI_TABLA
   (CAMPO1, CAMPO2, CAMPO3, CAMPO4, CAMPO5)
VALUES
   ( 312, 'PRUEBA2', 'PRUEBA2', 'PRUEBA2', 1);--Comentario que inhabilita mi linea

INSERT INTO MI_TABLA
   (CAMPO1, CAMPO2, CAMPO3, CAMPO4, CAMPO5)
VALUES
   ( 313, 'PRUEBA3', 'PRUEBA3', 'PRUEBA3', 1);

COMMIT;
```

Si ejecuto esto en la Base de datos me inserta únicaente PRUEBA1 y PRUEBA3 y sin embargo PRUEBA2 no aparece. Y lo peor es que no aparece error ninguno, simplemente la salida es que se han hecho 2 inserts (Sale 2 veces el mensaje 1 row created. y nada más).

¿Alguna idea de qué puede ser? ¿Se podría hacer de alguna forma que esto no se ingnorase para que funcionase o directamente diera algún error

Comment: Simplemente es una restricción de SQLPlus. No puede haber nada despues del punto y coma `;`. Puedes poner el comentario en la línea anterior o en la siguiente con `-- comentario` con `/* comentario */` o con `REM comentario`, pero nunca después del punto y coma.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Entiendo que es así y que no se puede poner, pero ¿porque no da ni un error? ¿Hay alguna forma de forzarle que ante estos casos, al menos, de error?

Comment: Otra cosa extraña que he visto es que si no se pone punto y coma, pero en la siguiente instrucción tras una linea en blanco se pone una instrucción acabada en punto y coma, entonces sí funciona (adjunto captura): [Captura](https://i.imgur.com/AFiEq1i.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de muchas pruebas y errores, finalmente obtuve una solución a mi problema. Espero que pueda ayudar a cualquiera con el mismo problema.

```
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON
```

La solución fue simple: escribir la siguiente línea en la primera línea del script o en el indicador de SQL:
Con esto, cuando la sentencia termina con un comentario después del punto y coma y también cuando no termina con punto y coma.